# Python Function that returns date from x days ago

Tags: python, function, date, datetime

I am trying to write a function which returns the date for x days ago. If a date is not given it should default to todays date.

```
def get_x_days_ago (x: date: datetime = datetime.today())
    return date_x_days_ago
```

Comment: Check out [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_x_days_ago(x, date=None):
    if date is None:
        date = datetime.now()
    return date - timedelta(days=x)

print(get_x_days_ago(1)) # 2021-04-26 15:43:53.448687

print(get_x_days_ago(365, datetime(2019, 1, 1))) # 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

If you want to `assert` the result with a `datetime.datetime` object. For example, Asserting if the "one day ago" result is the same as the `datetime` for one day ago.

`assert get_x_days_ago(1).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) == datetime(2021, 4, 26)`

If needed the return statement can instead be changed to

`return (date - timedelta(days=x)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

In your original question pre edit, you type annotated `datetime` as the type for `date` and also as the return type. If you don't care about the time part then you can instead pass a `datetime.date` object and do not have to deal with the `datetime.replace` method. **In other words**, the code becomes

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_x_days_ago(x, date_given=None):
    if date_given is None:
        date_given = date.today()
    return date_given - timedelta(days=x)

print(get_x_days_ago(1)) # this is of `datetime.date` type
assert get_x_days_ago(1) == date(2021, 4, 26)
print(get_x_days_ago(365, date(2019, 1, 1))) # so is this
```

Comment: how can I unit test that this function works? as the time element will always change.....      
  def test_get_x_days_ago(self):   self.assertEqual(get_x_days_ago(x=1, date_from=2021-4-22), 2021-4-21)      @python_user

Comment: @Girl007 if you want to assert with a datetime in string you can use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` on the result of `get_x_days_ago` so you only get a string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, something like `self.assertEqual(get_x_days_ago(x=1, date_from=2021-4-22).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '2021-04-21')`, if you want to change the format to match your assert rules, use `%d-%m-%y` instead of `%Y-%m-%d` and other related format